# Multiple AWS Accounts Trusted Advisor Consolidation

Tags: amazon-web-services

If you have Multiple AWS Accounts, how do you consolidate Trusted Advisor result without a 3rd part enterprise product? (I have already tried newscorpaus/consigliere and beeva/trusted-overlord. I had some implementation/installation problems with them)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to consolidate these reports without a 3rd party product. From speaking with our TAM, this is a highly requested feature and I'm sure will be an added capability sooner or later.